# Pan and Pinch a UIImageView within a ScrollView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have created a small app using a ScrollView w/ paging and a series of UIImageViews each representing a page.  It acts similar to the Photos.app.

I want to be able to pan and zoom individually for each image (page of a scrollview).

What would be the most sound approach to do this?  Should I replace the UIImageView page with a scrollview with a UIImage inside it?  I would then have a main scroll view where each page of the scrollview had a scrollview with an image inside it that could be pinched,etc.

It seems like a messy approach.  I am looking for a clean approach.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I know the approach you suggest is the way it is done. I have used this to create a PDF viewer and once everything is in place it doesn't feel too messy.

You might want to use CATiledLayer as your inner (per-page) scrollview's layer (instead of CALayer) if these images you have are really big (which could well be the case since otherwise zooming in on them would not bring you much but pixelation, but this is just an assumption on my part).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html). This controller manages a view controllers for each page and transitions between them using effects like page curl or scroll.

In your case you would create a view controller that manages a scrollview for zoom & pan for each page.